# Jqueryui dialog works just once

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have as script as you can see below:

```
<div id="divContentRating">
<div id="divAskForRating">
    Yeni tasarımımızı beğendiniz mi?
    <br />
    <a id="likeIcon" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/Images/like.jpg"/></a>
    <a id="neutralIcon" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/Images/neutral.jpg"/></a>
    <a id="unlikeIcon" href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="/Images/unlike.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div id="divPositiveRating">
    <div>
        <img src="/Images/like.jpg"/> Yeni tasarımımızı beğendiniz. <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divNegativeRating">
    <div>
        <img src="/Images/unlike.jpg"/> Yeni tasarımımızı beğenmediniz. <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="divNeutralRating">
    <div>
        <img src="/Images/neutral.jpg"/> Yeni tasarımımız hakkında görüşünüz yok. <br />
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="updateRate">Güncelle</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="negativeRatingReasonDialog" style="display: none">
    <div>
        Yeni tasarımımızı beğenmediniz.<br />
        <textarea id="Comment" rows="3"></textarea><br />
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="HasRated" value="false">
<input type="hidden" id="Rate" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="ContentKey" value="LANDING_PAGE">
<input type="hidden" id="RatingId" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="ParticipantId" value="">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var protocol = location.protocol;
    var host = window.location.host;

    if ($("#HasRated").val() == "true")
    {
        var rate = $("#Rate").val();
        if (rate == 1) {
            setPositiveRatedView();
        }
        else if (rate == 0) {
            setNeutralRatedView();
        }
        else if (rate == -1) {
            setNegativeRatedView();
        }
        else {
            setNotRatedView();
        }
    }
    else {
        setNotRatedView();
    }

    $("#likeIcon").click(function () {
        setPositiveRatedView();
        ratePage(1, "");
    });

    $("#neutralIcon").click(function () {
        setNeutralRatedView();
        ratePage(0, "");
    });

    $("#unlikeIcon").click(function () {
        setNegativeRatedView();
        alert("hey");
        DisplayCommentPopup();
    });

    $(".updateRate").click(function () {
        setNotRatedView();
    });

    function DisplayCommentPopup()
    {
        var dialogDiv = $("#negativeRatingReasonDialog");

        var _options = {
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 200, 
            height: 100, 
            close: function (ev, ui)
            {
                $(this).remove();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Paylaş": function() {
                    var comment = $("#Comment").val();
                    ratePage(-1, comment);
                    dialogDiv.dialog("close");
                },
                "Çıkış": function() {
                    ratePage(-1, "");
                    dialogDiv.dialog("close");
                }
            }
        };

        dialogDiv.dialog(_options);

        dialogDiv.dialog("open");
    }

    function setNotRatedView() {
        $("#divNeutralRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divPositiveRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divAskForRating").fadeIn();
        $("#divNegativeRating").fadeOut();
    }

    function setPositiveRatedView()
    {
        $("#divNegativeRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divNeutralRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divAskForRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divPositiveRating").fadeIn();
    }

    function setNegativeRatedView() {
        $("#divNeutralRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divPositiveRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divAskForRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divNegativeRating").fadeIn();
    }

    function setNeutralRatedView() {
        $("#divNegativeRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divPositiveRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divAskForRating").fadeOut();
        $("#divNeutralRating").fadeIn();
    }

    function ratePage(rating, comment)
    {
        var contentKey = $("#ContentKey").val();
        var hasRated = $("#HasRated").val();
        var ratingId = $("#RatingId").val();
        var participantId = $("#ParticipantId").val();

        var url = 
            protocol + '//' + host + '/ContentRating.aspx?contentKey=' + contentKey + '&rating=' + rating + '&ratingUpdate=' + hasRated + 
            '&ratingId=' + ratingId + '&participantId=' + participantId + '&comment=' + comment;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST', 
            cache: false,
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#HasRated").val(data.HasRated);
                $("#Rate").val(data.Rate);
                $("#ContentKey").val(data.ContentKey);
                $("#RatingId").val(data.RatingId);
                $("#ParticipantId").val(data.ParticipantId);
                $("#Comment").val(data.Comment);
                alert('HasRated: ' + data.HasRated + ' Rate: ' + data.Rate + ' ContentKey: ' + data.ContentKey + ' RatingId: ' + data.RatingId + ' ParticipantId: ' + data.ParticipantId + ' Comment: ' + data.Comment)
            },
            error: function( data ) {
                alert( 'ERROR:  ' + data );
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The dialog that I open in **DisplayCommentPopup** method appears only once. For the second try it doesn't work. How can I find the problem? Do you have any insights?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use firebug or another devTools and what error do you get? write request error message...

Comment: as @AliRızaAdıyahşi mentions, what is happening in firebug/devtools, is there a POST request happening in the network monitor section along with an associated response?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I found out that I'm getting 304, with "cache:false" parameter it is solved. but this time the dialog that is shown when the user click the unlike icon is shown olnly in the first time. I'm updating my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you close it you remove it so it cannot display:

```
 close: function (ev, ui) {
            $(this).remove();
        },
```

As an aside, I would rework the dialog code to be:

```
var dialogDiv = $("#negativeRatingReasonDialog");
var _options = {
    modal: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    autoOpen:false,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    close: function (ev, ui) {
       // $(this).remove();
    },
    buttons: {
        "Paylaş": function () {
            var comment = $("#Comment").val();
            ratePage(-1, comment);
            dialogDiv.dialog("close");
        },
            "Çıkış": function () {
            ratePage(-1, "");
            dialogDiv.dialog("close");
        }
    }
};

dialogDiv.dialog(_options);

function DisplayCommentPopup() {
     dialogDiv.dialog("open");
}
```

This way, it only gets "dialog" once, and then you can open it as needed: note the `autoOpen:false,` option added.

Comment: NOTE: I made it bigger as the textarea did not have room to display - do what you wish with that part.